# Batch file - restart program after every 20 minutes

Tags: batch-file

I want to create batch file which starts a program and after 20 minutes will close the program and start it again.

The only thing I know about a batch file is how to start a program:

```
@echo off
Start [adress of application]
```

Comment: You'll likely want to use schtasks.exe to schedule the task.  It will allow you to schedule a task for a certain time, and restrict how long it runs for.  If you want a more specific answer, then tell us what OS you are using.

Answer (score 24):

This works:

```
@echo off                           //Turn off screen text messages
:loop                               //Set marker called loop, to return to
start "Wicked_Article_Creator" "C:\Wicked Article Creator\Wicked Article Creator.exe"  //Start program, with title and program path 
timeout /t 1200 >null               //Wait 20 minutes
taskkill /f /im "Image Name" >nul   //Image name, e.g. WickedArticleCreator.exe, can be found via Task Manager > Processes Tab > Image Name column (look for your program)
timeout /t 7 >null                  //Wait 7 seconds to give your prgram time to close fully - (optional)
goto loop                           //Return to loop marker
```

Comment: I was looking for something similar , and it works absolutely fine. Just one thing though, the command prompt is visible the whole time. Is it possible to hide the cmd window and only show it when the exe is starting and then hide it again?

Answer (score 7):

```
@echo off
:loop
start yourtarget.exe ...
timeout /t 1200 >null
taskkill /f /im yourtarget.exe >nul
goto loop
```

should do the job.

Comment: I get Error invalid query: 'timeout' is not recognized as an internal or external command , operable program or batch program.

Comment: timeout.exe is an inbuilt utility that should have been provided with Windows. It has apparently been standard since W2000 **BUT** different editions may not include it. On my W7 Home Premium system, it's in c:\windows\system32 and there's a 64-bit version in c:\windows\syswow64. Try `dir /s \timeout.exe`. If the file is located, ensure that the directory it resides in is included in your PATH. If it's not located, try Googling `timeout.exe download`

Comment: after adding I get: ERROR invalid query

Comment: You'd need to say exactly the `TASKKill` line you used.

Comment: @echo off
:loop
start "" "C:\Wicked Article Creator\Wicked Article Creator.exe"
timeout /t 1200 >null
taskkill /f /im "C:\Wicked Article Creator\Wicked Article Creator.exe" >nul
goto loop

Comment: The image name is probably `"Wicked Article Creator.exe" - you've used the `filename`. While W.A.C is running, execute `tasklist` from the prompt to - well, duh, list the tasks and use your judgement as to which task it is. `tasklist | find /i "wicked"`may help. You may need to add a format switch to see the complete name, `tasklist /fo list`

Comment: For those that stumble across this old thread: Use /T parameter for full seconds (capital T) - Otherwise the limit is 99999 and that doesn't do much good in milliseconds.  Also, I had to remove all the comments from the batch so as not to be bad parameters when run.

Comment: @ClintStLaurent: The standard `timeout` supplied by Microsoft (at least in W7) ignores case fot `/t`. Perhaps some other third-party utilities make the distinction? Seems very much a *nixy thing to do to use case in options - very rarely done (if at all) in Microsoft utilities.

Comment: this assumes yourtarget.exe is a background process. The batch file will never continue if yourtarget.exe does not execute and run the rest of the batch file.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone coming across this old question:
Instead of timeout.exe you can also ping to an address that definitely doesn't exist:

```
ping 999.199.991.91 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
```

You can change 60000 to whatever delay you want (in ms).

```
1 second = 1000

10 seconds = 10000

60 seconds = 60000
```

And so on..

Comment: Sounds resource intensive compared to timeout.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo off                           
:loop                               
timeout /t 20 >null   ( Wait for 20 seconds before kill program)            
taskkill /F /IM terminal.exe  
timeout /t 3600 >null ( wait for 1hr before returning to loop or recycle the process)           
goto loop
```

I use another program called mt4bar to monitor my application and relaunch them anytime they crash or get closed