# Auto-restart a Program every hours with cooldown

Tags: batch-file

I'm looking for a script who can realize this sequence.

1. Close the Program every three hours;
2. Wait 30 seconds;
3. Relaunch the Program;

Can you help me manage this problem ? 
Thanks a lot !

Regards,

Comment: you coulod use taskkill look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: And `timeout` or `ping` can give you a 30 second delay.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a post here [Batch file - restart program after every 20 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602687/batch-file-restart-program-after-every-20-minutes?rq=1)

```
@echo off
:loop
start yourtarget.exe ...
timeout /t 1200 >null
taskkill /f /im yourtarget.exe >nul
goto loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Python is an option here:

```
import subprocess, time

while True:
    proc=subprocess.Popen("something.exe")
    time.sleep(3*60*60) # 3 hours
    proc.kill()
    time.sleep(30)  # 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@set /A _tic=%time:~0,2%*3600^
            +%time:~3,1%*10*60^
            +%time:~4,1%*60^
            +%time:~6,1%*10^
            +%time:~7,1% >nul

:: actual script

@set /A _toc=%time:~0,2%*3600^
            +%time:~3,1%*10*60^
            +%time:~4,1%*60^
            +%time:~6,1%*10^
            +%time:~7,1% >nul


: loop
 @set /A _elapsed=%_toc%-%_tic
 @echo %_elapsed% seconds.
  :: check for elapsed time here

  :: kill the app
  taskkill /im <yourappname>
  :: sleep for some time
  timeout /T 10

  :: start again
  start <yourappname>

goto loop
```