# How to i make a .bat that targets a program and types in a text box

Tags: batch-file, windows-8.1, minecraft

I have no idea where to start on this one. I have seen answers that are like  this but I don't know how to format them for what I want. I just need to target the minecraft server while its open and close it by typing "stop" in the console. I have no code to show for but this will be in a other file so I can launch it and then have it close the program. btw I don't think I can use `taskkill` But anything will help ;) thankyou very much!

Comment: Have you looked at [`mcrcon`](https://bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers.70910/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using a batch file alone.  There are two main ways to get input to another program in the system (in this case, java.exe):

1. Get your program to listen for a special signal.  There are several administrative plugins for Minecraft which will run in the Java process and will do what you need.
2. Spoof user input to the program.  In the case of a console app, you would probably use a SendKeys() based solution.  See [How to send input to the console as if the user is typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451228/how-to-send-input-to-the-console-as-if-the-user-is-typing) for some examples.

In the case of Minecraft, I think the first solution is going to be significantly easier, because the modding community has already supplied a number of solutions to this exact problem.  @Frxstrem recommended [mcrcon](https://bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers.70910/), which I suppose is as good a solution as any.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the console client you are using is scriptable and this is not good aproach.

Any way here's a [sendKeys.bat](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat). You can use it like:

```
call sendKeys.bat "Minecraft console title" "stop{enter}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch files can't do this without calling out to something else; if you're going to call to something else, use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) - that's what it's good at.

`WinActivate "the title of the Minecraft server window"`

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

`Send stop{Enter}`

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

Comment: Thankyou sll for responding so quickly I even had enough time to make icecream and I refreshed the page and BAM now my program works great thanks you guys! ;)