# in batch how do i use taskkill properly

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

I need to shutdown a program (minecraft server).  I think `taskkill` will do the job

```
@echo on
TASKKILL /F /IM Minecraft server /T
echo killed!
```

I asked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539878/how-to-i-make-a-bat-that-targets-a-program-and-types-in-a-text-box) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519968/batch-text-pasteing-stoping) of how to auto type "stop" in the console of the server, but they didn't work. I don't want to  download any extra programs. Just batch, VBScript, or Java. I would prefer batch though.

Hope I made some sense anyway thanks!

Comment: minecraft_server.exe is just a wrapper for a bunch of Java files. When you run it, the only new program that appears in the Tasklist is `javaw.exe`. If you aren't running any other Java programs at the same time as the Minecraft server, you can kill `javaw.exe`.

Comment: You really don't want to `taskkill` your Minecraft server to stop it.  There is a very high chance you will corrupt your world.

Comment: Edit for formatting. Links to referenced questions. Words

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('tasklist^|find /i "javaw.exe"') do (set pid=%%a)
echo %pid%
taskkill /pid %pid%
pause
```

This will get the PID (temporary "ID" for a proccess/task), and kill it/the source.
This will take a random "javaw.exe" though, so if you have more than one 'javaw.exe' / java proccess open at a time, it will take a random one, find its' PID and kill it. But as for my experience when running a Minecraft server you dont want to have many unnessecary programs open in the Background - so you can safely use this as long as you only run one 'javaw.exe' at a time :)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct [Syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) for [Taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)

```
taskkill [/s Computer] [/u Domain\User [/p Password]]] [/fi FilterName] [/pid ProcessID]|[/im ImageName] [/f][/t]
```

To kill [Minecraft Server](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/server-support/server-administration/1906029-automatic-backup-of-minecraft-server)

```
TaskKill /F /IM javaw.exe
```

Hope this Helps.