# Batch file timeout to terminate current command and execute next one

Tags: windows, batch-file, timeout

I am currently running simulation on my computer using batch files to make the thing a bit more automatic rather than having to launch every simulation myself once the previous one is finished.

I noticed however that when I run my batch file if one of the simulation isn't able to complete and just keeps running for hours I have no way to skip to terminate it and skip to the next one. This means that if it trips on the second simulation out of my 200... well I lost a weekend's worth of simulation time.

I was wondering if one of you could tell me how to include a "timer" condition to the execution so that after 5hrs of running it terminates and moves on to the next command.

For info, my file look like this (ogs is my executable and the path is where the executable looks for the inputs and then it prints the consol to a file called Screen_out.txt):

```
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_40_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_40_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_174_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_174_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_350_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_350_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
```

I've got 200 of those lines or so but I generate them automatically using a Python script so I don't mind a repetitive solution which looks like that, as it will just be a matter of adding it to the string I use to create the batch file:

```
set timer to 5hrs, if timer is reached terminate and move on
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_40_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_40_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
set timer to 5hrs, if timer is reached terminate and move on
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_174_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_174_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
set timer to 5hrs, if timer is reached terminate and move on
ogs Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_350_Perm_100\ax    >    Depth_200_Poro_15_Thick_350_Perm_100\Screen_out.txt
```

I had a look around but it seems that under Windows the timeout command only pauses the execution rather than terminates it.

I have tried the following using, [How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7):

```
start   "ogs    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\ax    >    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\Screen_out.txt"
timeout /t 10
taskkill /im ogs.exe /f 
timeout /t 7
```

The above seems to work, the program executes and shuts down after 10 seconds but the command window which opens with the

```
start   "ogs    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\ax    >    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\Screen_out.txt"
```

doesn't close when ogs.exe is killed.

---- 29/07/2016 UPDATE -----

So at the moment I am using the following:

```
start cmd /c    "ogs    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\ax    >    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\Screen_out.txt" //executes the command as before
timeout /t 34000// waits for 34000 seconds
taskkill /im ogs.exe /f // terminates the program after the 10 seconds
timeout /t 7 // waits 10 seconds to insure the program has terminated correctly
```

My problem is that when my program ogs.exe finished before 34000 seconds the computer will wait for the timeout before launching the next ogs.exe run. I would like it to wait for maximum 34000 seconds BUT to move on to the next run if the program finishes before the 34000 second timeout

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7), check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18045226/1871033)

Comment: I had a look at this yesterday and tried a few different things (see edit at the bottom of the question)  but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: 1) You forgot to describe what "without success" means. What happened? 2) I guess what didn't succeed is the file redirection. You need `start cmd /c "ogs blabla > blabla"` for it to work. 3) Actually I recommended the other answer, see my link, so you don't *always* wait until the timeout, if the simulation actually finished before that. 4) You need `ogs.exe` and not `ogs` in your `taskkill`.

Comment: got it to work ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @CherryDT managed to get it to work using:

```
start cmd /c    "ogs    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\ax    >    Depth_4000_Poro_23_Thick_350_Perm_650\Screen_out.txt" //executes the command as before
timeout /t 10 // waits for 10 seconds
taskkill /im ogs.exe /f // terminates the program after the 10 seconds
timeout /t 7 // waits 10 seconds to insure the program has terminated correctly
```

other useful thread here: [Batch file - restart program after every 20 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602687/batch-file-restart-program-after-every-20-minutes)

[How to set a timeout for a process under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515254/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-a-process-under-windows-7)